# Nodejs with socket.io on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to run a nodejs application with express and socket.io on heroku and it comess out with this error

EACCESS, Permission denied

when i try to run following code:

```
app.configure(function () {
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'))
io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // it crashes on this line
io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
    io.set("log level", 1);
});
```

Is it even possible to do this on heroku?

dependencies:

```
"socket.io": "*",
"express": "3.0.0rc4",
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this link: [using socket.io with node.js on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku).

[**UPDATE 1**]

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944579/1647507), which I think can help you troubleshooting your problem.

[**UPDATE 2**]

A [link to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962995/socket-io-chat-app-on-heroku-with-node-js) that has working code (regardless of the client's bug, the motivation of the question itself).

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = require('express').createServer()
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(port);

// Heroku setting for long polling
io.configure(function () { 
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
    io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});

// To set handlers for data received, etc ... use io.sockets.on('...', ...)
```

Comment: i thought that i could only use process.env.PORT (thats the port tha heroku assigns to me), without that i would just get different error that i dint use some random port

Comment: i dont think that link can help me, since all of that is after the .listen()

Comment: that last piece of code uses express 2.x, and i'm using 3.x (dont remember why, had some problem with 2.x). but yeah maybe somewhere there is the issue, but i still dont know what is it or how to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

What does it do when you:

```
io = require('socket.io');
app.configure(function () {
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'))
io.listen(server); // it crashes on this line
io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
    io.set("log level", 1);
});
```

I realize that shouldn't do anything differently, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just starting 2 servers on the same port - your `app` (express server) and this one `server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'))`

Try to write this

```
server = http.createServer(app).listen(/*port not from app*/)
```